# how to assign array values into dynamically created textboxes using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i have created a list of textboxes through for loop using Jquery Mobile. I need to populate text to these textboxes from an array list. i have tried using following code, which was not working properly.

```
var myArray = ["Lion","Tiger","Deer","Elephant","Zebra"];
<div class="ui-grid-a"></div>
```

script tag contains;

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
var content = '<div class="ui-block-a">'
content += '<input data-role="none" type="text" id="textboxId" readonly/>'
$('#textboxId').val(myArray[i]);
content += '</div>'
$('.ui-grid-a').append(content);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access an element that is not yet added to `DOM`, you can add value to `textbox` that time you adding it in content string. Note you are using same `id` for all textboxes that is also wrong. You can append `i` to `id` of textbox to make `id` unique.

```
content += '<input id="textboxId"'+i+'" readonly value="' + myArray[i] + '" data-role="none" type="text" />'
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to have different ids for each divs.

```
var myArray = ["Lion","Tiger","Deer","Elephant","Zebra"];

for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    var content = '<div class="ui-block-a">'
    content += '<input data-role="none" type="text" id="textboxId_'+i+'" readonly/>'
    content += '</div>'
    $('.ui-grid-a').append(content);
    $('#textboxId_'+i).val(myArray[i]);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9C9YG/)

Comment: Welcome.. Better if you can accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = ["Lion","Tiger","Deer","Elephant","Zebra"];
<div class="ui-grid-a"></div>
```

Your Script:

```
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
           var content = '<div class="ui-block-a">'
           content += '<input id="textboxId '+i+'" readonly value="' + myArray[i] + '"data-role="none   "type="text" />'
           $('.ui-grid-a').append(content);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
var myArray = ["Lion","Tiger","Deer","Elephant","Zebra"];
for(i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {      
      $("<div />", {
          "class" : "ui-block-a"
      }).append($("<input />", {
          "data-role": "none",
          "value": myArray[i],
          "type" :"text",
          "readonly": true
      })).appendTo(".ui-grid-a");
}
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Up9yu/)